# How to remove blinking cursor from readOnly field?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJs `ng-readonly` attribute its working as expected but i have a requirement where user dont want to see blinking cursor when user click in the `textarea`. is there any Angular way to resolve the issue ?

main.html

```
<textarea class="form-control"
    placeholder="Risk Event Type Description" id="riskEventTypeDesc"
    k-data-text-field="'text'"
    ng-model="riskEventObj.riskEventTypeDescription"
    name="RiskEventTypeDesc"  ng-readonly="true">
</textarea>
```

Comment: You shouldn't even be able to click in the `textarea` if you're using `ng-readonly`, shouldn't even be possible to see a blinking cursor in this case.

Comment: Its happening in IE browser and if i use ng-disabled it will restrict user to scroll the text

Comment: `<textarea onfocus=blur() readonly></textarea>`

Comment: Use a `pre` instead?

Comment: You're gonna run into more problems if you need to support IE. For one thing, IE9 and lower does not support placeholder text, so your textarea will appear empty in that browser unless you use a polyfill or other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Based on dandavis's comment, you can write a custom directive for this:

```
app.directive("forceReadonly", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on("focus", function(){
        if(this.readonly) {
          this.blur();
        }
      });

      scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        element.off("focus");
      })
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Risk Event Type Description" id="riskEventTypeDesc" ng-readonly="isReadonly" force-readonly>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
```

Whenever the `textarea` gets focus the directive checks whether the `textarea` is readonly or not. If it's readonly it removes the focus instantly, so you won't see the blinking caret.

This way scrolling will work as well.

Example fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d3eyLdz2/2/).

There is a drawback though, which might make this not unusable for you: this takes away the ability to select text in the `textarea`, therefore no copying from the `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

I know doing it in angular is the "cool" way to do it. But CSS might give you the ability to do this as well.

I made a JS fiddle if it helps demonstrate the differences in CSS attributes you could potentially use.

https://jsfiddle.net/qdmadqLe/

```
<span style="cursor:inherit">inherit</span><br>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: How is the mouse cursor related to the blinking caret in a textarea? These two are mixed up so often.

Comment: Sorry my man, I thought you meant when the user's mouse was hovering over it.. My bad.